# udp point to point communication on windows multi-homed server

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp, boost-asio

In my multicast receiver application I join a group and receive multicast data successfully. 
Also, there's an api for filling any gaps. This uses udp. When a gap is detected a retransmission request is sent. There's a thread dedicated to receiving and processing udp datagrams that come back in response to a request. 
This all worked fine on a windows machine with one interface card. Now we need to get this to run on a multi-homed machine with 2 NIC cards.
To get the multicast to work we had to add routes so that the app would send the joins out the correct NIC. Again, this part works fine.

However, the point to point udp receive_from method throws an error immediately upon entry. My understanding is that the sender_endpoint is initialized with the method itself. Do I need to do something special for this udp socket to not throw errors upon entry? Do I need to bind the socket in some way or set up special routes at the host level?
Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the error that comes back:
 ERR:reRequestMoldUdp64::waitForResponseNT got error:An invalid argument was supplied

```
boost::asio::ip::address    m_targetIP;     
short                       m_port;
udp::endpoint           m_receiver_endpoint;
m_receiver_endpoint.address(m_targetIP);
m_receiver_endpoint.port(m_port);   

if (!m_socket.is_open()) {  
        openUdpSocket();
}

while (1)
{
        m_last_ReceiveLen = 0;
        udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

        try {
            //m_last_ReceiveLen = m_socket.receive_from( (boost::asio::buffer(m_Buffer, max_length)), sender_endpoint);
            m_last_ReceiveLen = m_socket.receive_from( (boost::asio::buffer(m_Buffer, max_length)), sender_endpoint, 0, ec);
            if (ec) {
                _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf), "%s got error:%s", __FUNCTION__, ec.message().c_str());
                MyLog(LOG_ERROR, logBuf);
                myExit(__FILE__, __LINE__, 1);  
            }
        }

        catch (std::exception& e) {                 
            _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf), "INFO:%s sender_endpoint.address[%s] error:[%s]",
                            __FUNCTION__, 
                            sender_endpoint.address().to_string().c_str(),
                            e.what());
            MyLogAlways(logBuf);
            if (!m_socket.is_open()) {  
                openUdpSocket();
            }           
            if (++m_waitForResponseNTRetryCnt > 100) {
                myExit(__FILE__, __LINE__, 1);          
            }
            else {
                Sleep(100);     // 100 ms
                continue;           
            }
        }
        std::string dummyStr;
        const UINT64 dummySeqno(0);
        udpResponseAPI(BuildMap,dummySeqno, dummyStr);
    }
}

void reRequestMoldUdp64::openUdpSocket()
{
    char logBuf[512];

    if (!m_socket.is_open()) {      
        m_socket.open(udp::v4(), m_Error);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }   

    if (!m_socket.is_open()) {      
        _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf), "%s udp socket didn't reopen error:[%s]", __FUNCTION__, m_Error.message().c_str());
        MyLog(LOG_ERROR, logBuf);       
    }
    else {          
        _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf), "%s udp socket successfully opened", __FUNCTION__);
        MyLogAlways(logBuf);
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void reRequestMoldUdp64::sendRequest(std::string request)
{   
    MyLog("INFO:Begin sendRequest");

    m_lastRequestSent = request;

    char myBuff[128];
    int len(request.length());
    memcpy(myBuff, request.c_str(), len);   
#if 0
    _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf), "INFO:Before sendto() len:%d ip:%s port:%hu",
                len,
                m_receiver_endpoint.address().to_string().c_str(),
                m_receiver_endpoint.port()
                );

    MyLogAlways(logBuf);
#endif
    _snprintf(logBuf, sizeof(logBuf),"%s sending udp rerequest to:%s", __FUNCTION__, 
                                                m_receiver_endpoint.address().to_string().c_str());
    MyLogAlways(logBuf);

    if (m_socket.is_open()) {
        m_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(myBuff, len), m_receiver_endpoint);    
    }
    else {
        m_socket.open(udp::v4(), m_Error);
        m_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(myBuff, len), m_receiver_endpoint);    
        MyLogAlways("ERR:reRequest socket is not open");
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to add routes, you should be able to just `bind()` the socket to the desired NIC before then having the socket join the multicast group.

Comment: Remy, the multicast code is working fine. This is for udp point to point communication a different socket etc. This code is running on a separate thread and is used to fill gaps when a multicast packet is dropped.

Comment: That does not negate what I said.

Comment: After playing around with the code I discovered that I needed to do two things to get this to work. 1) Initial the senderEndpoint for ip/port 2) More critically do this in the initializer list where my constructor is invoked.

Comment: Unfortunately my statement above about it working is not correct. It did work a few times, but now I am back to getting the same error. There must be something more fundamental here that I am not understanding. The key difference is that we went from a server with one NIC to a server with two NIC's. I didn't do a bind before in the one NIC environment and all worked well. Is it that on a mult-homed server a bind is now required?

Comment: Sorry about this. I issued a bounty and gave up 50 points. However it looks like I had a small bug in my application that was causing this weird error and am currently verifying.

Comment: Still having the same problem. I get the error intermittently on some startups when I first call receive_from. Haven't determined the pattern as yet. My main question at this point is this: On a multihomed windows server do I need to do a bind after the open for the udp socket receive_from is running on? On a one NIC server I have been running the code for over 6 months and haven't had a problem without the bind. The udp client/server examples do not use a socket bind method.

Comment: You always have to `bind()` a listening socket before you can read from it.  Not only does it need to know what NIC(s) to listen on, but it also needs to know which port number to listen on. You can't use `receive_from()` without establishing the receiving port number first.

Comment: okay, After a little more reading and seeing your comment  I have come to the following code. The any() should cover all the NIC interfaces and the zero(0) for listening port was suggested as well. Does this sound correct to you?    boost::system::error_code ec;

if (!m_socket.is_open()) {  
 m_socket.open(udp::v4(), m_Error);    
 m_socket.bind(udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 0), ec);
 if (ec) {
 // log something 
 }
}

Comment: boost::system::error_code ec;  

if (!m_socket.is_open()) {    
 m_socket.open(udp::v4(), m_Error);    
 m_socket.bind(udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 0), ec);  
 if (ec) {  
 // log something   
 }  
}

Comment: First, don't put code in comments like that. Edit your question to show your latest code. Second, binding to `any()` is fine, if you want to receive data from any network that the receiver PC is connected to. But do you really want to bind to port 0? That will cause the socket to bind to the first available random ephemeral port that is available. How is the sender supposed to know which random port the receiver is listening on? You need to bind to the port number that the sender will be sending packets to.

Comment: In doing some reading and experimenting I see that the sender (ie server side) simply responds to the source ip/source port contained in the client side request. In my application the sender only ever responds upon receipt of a request. So defaulting to a random ephemeral port works fine for the client However, picking a port in advance does have the advantage of making it a bit easier to troubleshoot problems using wireshark.